# how to use css in JS for nested hover styles, Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I'm using Material UI and trying to convert normal css classes into js file.

```css
.nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navItem {
    float: left;
    flex: 1;
}

.navLink {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-size: '1 rem';
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.6;
    letter-spacing: '0.0075em';
    opacity: 1;
    text-transform: 'none';
    min-width: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.navLink-static {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-size: '1rem';
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.6;
    letter-spacing: '0.0075em';
    opacity: 1;
    text-transform: 'none';
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.navLink:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid mediumvioletred;
    background: #8DB8DD;
    cursor: pointer;
}

 .navLink:hover > div:hover {
      border-bottom: none;
 }

.navLink.active {
    font-weight: 600;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px solid orange;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul className={classes.nav}>
    <li className={classes.navItem}>
        <NavLink className={classes.navLink} to="/" exact>
            abc
        </NavLink>
    </li>
    <li className={classes.navItem}>
        <NavLink className={classes.navLink} to="/def" exact>
            def
        </NavLink>
    </li>
    <li className={classes.navItem}>
        <NavLink className={classes.navLink} to="/ghi">
            ghi
        </NavLink>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How do I convert these css styles in material ui pattern. I do not see any examples on how to set 'active' state and nested hover style for an element. More documentation related to this kind of advance scenarios helps.

Here is how much further I've gone in converting these..

```js
const styles = theme => ({
    nav: {
        listStyleType: 'none',
        margin: 0,
        padding: 0,
        overflow: 'hidden'
    },
    navItem: {
        float: 'left',
        flex: 1
    },
    navLink: {
        color: 'white',
        textDecoration: 'none',
        display: 'block',
        fontSize: '1rem',
        fontWeight: 500,
        lineHeight: 1.6,
        letterSpacing: '0.0075em',
        opacity: 1,
        textTransform: 'none',
        minWidth: 0,
        padding: '10px',
        marginLeft: '10px',
        marginRight: '10px',
        '&:hover': {
            borderBottom: '2px solid mediumvioletred',
            background: '#8DB8DD',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            // '& div': {
            //     '&:hover': {
            //         borderBottom: 'none',
            //     }
            // },
            '&> div &:hover': {
                borderBottom: 'none',
            }
        },
        // 'div:hover': {
        //     borderBottom: 'none',
        // },

    },
    navLinkStatic: {
        color: 'white',
        textDecoration: 'none',
        display: 'block',
        fontSize: '1rem',
        fontWeight: 500,
        lineHeight: 1.6,
        letterSpacing: '0.0075em',
        opacity: 1,
        textTransform: 'none',
        padding: '10px',
        marginLeft: '10px',
        marginRight: '10px',
    }
});
```

How can I convert this into material style 
**.navLink:hover > div:hover {**

Things I have tried.

```css
navLink: {

        '&:hover': {
            borderBottom: '2px solid mediumvioletred',
            background: '#8DB8DD',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            // '& div': {
            //     '&:hover': {
            //         borderBottom: 'none',
            //     }
            // },
            // '&> div &:hover': {
            //     borderBottom: 'none',
            // }
        },
        '&:hover > div:hover': {
            borderBottom: 'none'
        }

    },
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `navLink: {
  '&:hover > div:hover' {
  }
}`?

Comment: @Jörn yes, did not work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The correct syntax is `"&:hover > div:hover": { ... }`.

Here is a working example demonstrating the syntax:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  navlink: {
    border: "1px solid green",
    fontSize: "16pt",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "lightgreen"
    },
    "&:hover > div:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "lightblue"
    }
  }
});
function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className={classes.navlink}>
        Hello <div>CodeSandbox</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit nested div hover]

It also works to deeply nest with this syntax:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  navlink: {
    border: "1px solid green",
    fontSize: "16pt",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "lightgreen",
      "& > div:hover": {
        backgroundColor: "lightblue"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit nested div hover]

Here is the relevant JSS documentation: https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested/?v=v10.0.0-alpha.24

Related answer:

- [How do you change a style of a child when hovering over a parent using material-ui jss styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59178802/how-do-you-change-a-style-of-a-child-when-hovering-over-a-parent-using-material/59179458#59179458)

Comment: How would you select another object? Such as an onHover effect, `const useStyles = makeStyles({ elementA: { color: 'blue' }, elementB: { "&:hover $elementA": { color: 'ref' } } });`, where onHover on elementB, I want to change the color of elementA from blue to red?