# How to display div element on hover another element using css-in-js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, css-in-js

I'm trying to display some information only on hover to special div. I'm using material ui and their withStyles component. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Would a Tooltip cover your need? https://material-ui.com/components/tooltips/

Comment: Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57716926/how-to-use-css-in-js-for-nested-hover-styles-material-ui/57729101#57729101

Comment: @DavisJones Tooltip from material-ui is good solution, but I need a lot of customization in my case. Not sure that I could do it.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thanks! It looks like an elegant solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this example:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

export default function ShowButtonHover() {
    const [style, setStyle] = useState({display: 'none'});

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h2>Hidden message in the box. Move mouse in the box</h2>
            <div style={{border: '1px solid gray', width: 300, height: 300, padding: 10, margin: 100}}
                 onMouseEnter={e => {
                     setStyle({display: 'block'});
                 }}
                 onMouseLeave={e => {
                     setStyle({display: 'none'})
                 }}
            >
                <div style={style}>This was hidden</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I checked this example, it works. Although keep such style property in state seems a little bit overhead, it solves the problem.

Comment: @Tatiana Thank you so much

Comment: But I still not sure that keep styles in component state is really right way :) Maybe I miss something

Comment: As this is just an example, so if you have many styles then you write those styles in css class into a css file then you can use setClassName("your-css-class"). then I am sure you will be worried anymore.